# Should return to list after adding new item/product?

Tags: navigation, lists

I have a dashboard where there are some areas where users can manage items and products. For example: News, Products, Clients, etc...

Each area has basically 2 views:

- List: Contain all the items of that area - [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbIaZ.png);
- Add/Edit: View to add a new item, or edit an existing one - [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/te5L7.png);

So, my question is: When users add a new item, should they stay on the same page, but now with the option to edit? Or should I return them back to the main list, now with the new item on the list as well?

The main reason why I'm thinking about this, is because the list view doesn't show all the information, so Users could check for information that may have been inserted wrong.

However, I don't think there will be much cases where the information will be incorrect to the point users need to check everything again after each new Item added.

Is there any other consideration I should have in mind when designing this type of interaction.

Comment: Is it likely that users will want to add another item after adding one?

Comment: @EricStoltz partially. There are areas where just one each day (news, for example), but there are other areas where it can be more than 1 in a row, or short period of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask your potential users what they prefer. If you don't have a connection to your app potential customers, let them choose by interface:

[image]

After the launch, you should measure how often customers click on every button and make a decision based on that data.